# Quadrature for integrating a univariate function twice

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm looking to investigate quadrature-like rules that can evaluate
$$
\int_a^b \int_a^s f(t) \, dt \, ds
$$
for sufficiently smooth real univariate functions $f$ by only using point evaluations of $f$. I assume that this is a classical problem, but I cannot seem to find the right keywords to properly search it. What are some known methods, and what is the correct keyword to search for in the literature?

*Background:* Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$. A quadrature rule is a method to approximate a definite integral
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \approx \sum_{i=1}^n w_i f(x_i)
$$
for appropriate values of $w_i, x_i$, accurate given that $f$ is sufficiently smooth. Thus a quadrature approximates an integral using point evaluations of $f$. If $f$ is a velocity function, then its definite integral can be viewed as the total position displacement from time $a$ to $b$.

I'm interested in the equivalent situation where $f$ is an expression for acceleration. If $f$ is acceleration, then the total displacement from time $a$ to $b$ is given by
$$
v_a(b-a) + \int_a^b \int_a^s f(t) \, dt \, ds,
$$
where $v_a$ is the initial velocity at time $a$.

Comment: In this specific case, there's [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ah, that is excellent. It does not fully address my  problem because I'd also like to consider a more general case, but this is already very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note that,
$$
\int_a^b \underbrace{\int_a^s f(t) dt}_{g(s)} ds = \int_a^b g(s) ds \approx  \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i g(s_i)
$$

On the other hand,

$$
g(s_i) = \int_a^{s_i} f(t) dt \approx \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} \omega_{ij} f(t_j)
$$

So, finally

$$
\int_a^b \int_a^s f(t) dt\, ds\approx \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} \omega_{ij} f(t_j).
$$

Unless I'm missing something, there is really nothing nonstandard here.

---

Here's another idea... In general,

$$
\int_a^b \int_a^s f(t,s) dt ds = \int_a^b \int_t^b f(t,s) ds dt
$$

but, if $f=f(t)$ does not depend on $s$, this becomes

$$
\int_a^b f(t)(b-t) dt \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i f(t_i) (b-t_i).
$$

Comment: The computation of $g(s_i)$ by quadrature requires different nodes for each $s_i$ (in other words, $t_j$ is also a function of $s_i$). Thus if each instance of quadrature requires $n$ nodes, the final quadrature rule would require $n^2$ nodes, which greatly exceeds the order of standard quadrature.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong You did not mention any concerns on computational load in your post... The overall number  of nodes should be smaller than $n^2$ because the number of quadrature nodes may be smaller for smaller $s$. It would be more like $\frac 12 n^2 +n$.

Comment: You're right, I did not specify. Generally I'm interested in extensions of Gauss-type quadratures, for which O(n) nodes will be required to integrate polynomials of degree n. This linear complexity is generally desired due to the connection between quadrature and interpolation.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I added to my answer... I think this migth be it :)

Comment: Thank you Pierre, that is very nice. I'll have to think about how to generalize...